# Is it possible to create a Cauchy product if the series doesn't have a zeroth term?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm working with an integral something like

$$I = \int_0^L \left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1-(-1)^k)}{k}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)e^{1/k}x \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(1-(-1)^m)}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)e^{1/m}\right]\,dx.$$

I'm not convinced that this isn't able to be simplified in some meaningful way, especially since I may be able to use the fact that only odd $k$ and $m$ terms are non-trivial. I'm trying to rewrite this somehow so I can use the orthogonality of the sin terms in the integral to reduce the sums even more but I'm not sure how I would do this.

Is it still possible to use the Cauchy product even when the zeroth sequence term is not well-defined or does the equality
$$\left(\sum_{n=z}^\infty x_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=z}^\infty y_n \right) = \sum_{n=z}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n x_k y_{n-k}$$
still hold for $z \ge 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it's easy enough to adjust the indices so that there is a zeroth term.  Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1 - (-1)^k)}{k} = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty \frac{(1 - (-1)^{j+1})}{j+1}.$$

The partial sums of each series are identical.  (This is a "change of variables" for series.)  From here you can apply the usual Cauchy product formula.